# How can I use AccessibilityService to retrieve content of other apps running..?

Tags: android

- I'm working in Accessibility Service. i need to get the app name using Accessibility Service. i have studied the documentation of the Accessibility Service in developer's of Android website. but there is no mention about getting the app name using Accessibility.
- I also want to extract text from "TextViews" of the other apps(Activities) running in background. How i can  do this..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you know how to implement an AccessibilityService.

Retrieving window content:

First register for `TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED` events.

```
 @Override
 public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent){
     int eventType = accessibilityEvent.getEventType();

     switch (eventType) {

         case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED:

             AccessibilityNodeInfo rootNode = getRootInActiveWindow();
             ArrayList<AccessibilityNodeInfo> textViewNodes = new ArrayList<AccessibilityNodeInfo>();

             findChildViews(rootNode);

             for(AccessibilityNodeInfo mNode : textViewNodes){
                if(mNode.getText()==null){
                    return;
                }
                String tv1Text = mNode.getText().toString();

                //do whatever you want with the text content...

             }
         break;

     }
 }
```

Method `findChildViews()` :

```
private void findChildViews(AccessibilityNodeInfo parentView) {
        if (parentView == null || parentView.getClassName() == null || ) {
            return;
        }

        if (childCount == 0 && (parentView.getClassName().toString().contentEquals("android.widget.TextView"))) {
            textViewNodes.add(parentView);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                findChildViews(parentView.getChild(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As far as i know, there's no assured way to get the app name, but you can try fetching the text content from the event object you get from `TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED` events.

Try dumping `accessibilityEvent.toString()` & you'll know what i'm talking about.

Also, `accessibilityEvent.getPackageName()` is a simple way to get package name of that app; in case you find it useful!

Comment: Is it also possible to get content of imageview (bitmap or something)?

Answer (score 4):

previous answer is missing definition of childCount

int childCount = parentView.getChildCount();